# Encryption password required for restore

Tags: encryption, restore

I have reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04.03 to clear a black screen on boot. I have my files backed up to an external hard drive but when I try to run restore I am asked for an encryption password, which I was not asked for when I backed up the files. I use a Toshiba Satellite C50-B-14D. Can anyone advise how to restore my files please?

Comment: What application are you using for backups?

Comment: I am voting to close because this describes a problem that can't be reproduced, that seemingly went away on its own or was only relevant to a very specific period of time. It's off-topic as it's unlikely to help future readers. A question describing that you forgot, and then remembered your password would not be helpful to anyone else.

Comment: Matigo - the backup app supplied in utilities when I loaded ubuntu. 

Nmath - I have been using ubuntu for 2 weeks and nowhere in documentation could I find a reference to the backup app applying an encryption password so felt that I had to ask for help, please forgive me as a new user. I agree that the topic should be closed and hoped that my explanatory comment would keep others from wasting their time on a solved problem

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved - I tried an old administrator password which I thought had been removed and the restore operation worked